# CloudFormation, Lambda, S3 - Access denied by s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

So I am trying to run this cloudformation script but I get this error:

> - **`Your access has been denied by S3, please make sure your request credentials have permission to GetObject for s3.XXXX.amazonaws.com/s3-bucket/folder-1/folder-2/code.zip. S3 Error Code: AccessDenied. S3 Error Message: Access Denied`**

I've even tried making my code.zip public! which is not what I want to do ideally...

**Here is my code:**

```
"lambdafunction": {
     "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
     "DependsOn": [
         "other1",
         "other2",
         "other3"
     ],
     "Properties": {
         "Code": {
             "S3Bucket": "s3.XXXX.amazonaws.com",
             "S3Key": "s3-bucket/folder-1/folder-2/code.zip"
         },
         "Role": {
             "Fn::GetAtt": [
                 "accessrole",
                 "Arn"
             ]
         },
         "Timeout": 60,
         "Handler": "lambda_function.lambda_handler",
         "Runtime": "python2.7",
         "MemorySize": 1024
     },
     "Metadata": {
         "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
             "id": "XXXX"
         }
     }
 },
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume you are using the aws-cli. If so does the IAM user that you have used to log in to aws-cli has permission to GetObject from S3 ?

Comment: thanks for getting back to me Asanka! No this is in the cloudformation service on the aws console, I've tried adding policies onto the s3 bucket to allow the cloud formation to have access and making sure the selected role has the correct permissions to access the bucket also! I can't seem to figure out why its throwing this error!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out the code section was wrong and needed to name the bucket url

```
 "Code": {
     "S3Bucket": "s3-bucket",
     "S3Key": "folder-1/folder-2/code.zip"
 },
```

Comment: You should provide an example of the expected format. Is it simply the bucket name, or the URI with s3:// prepended?